# Php pdo pagination with FULL JOIN continuous result

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

i dont know what is wrong with this code but if i use FULL JOIN the pagination continuous on the JOINed table. I mean if the JOINed table have more rows than first table, the result is empty html table but with many pages.
If i remove the JOINed table the result is normal table with 5-6 rows. But when JOIN and the table become with 5-6 rows with info and 100 with empty cells.
Any advices for this code? Or i have to use other code? I cant beleive that pagination is such a pain, cant find good working code.
Thank you in advance!
Here is the trouble code:

```
{
/* Set the number of results to display on each page. */
$rowsPerPage = 20;

try
{
    //$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paerp.dbo.Truck';
    // simple query
    //$stmtcount = $pdo->query( $query );
    //$rowcountall = $stmtcount;
/* Order target data by ID and select only items (by row number) to display        on a given page. 
   The query asks for one "extra" row as an indicator that another page of    data exists. */
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.id desc) 
            AS RowNumber, d.id as iddr, d.SqlInsertDate, d.PACourceNumber,    d.ClientQuerydate, d.ClientName, d.SpeditorName, d.CourseType, d.Driver1, d.Driver2, d.TruckRegisteredNumber,          d.TrailerRegisteredNumber, d.StartWorkingDay, d.LoadingAddress, d.UnloadingAddress, d.AgreedLoadingDay, d.ArrivalLoadingDay, d.DateTimeLoading, d.AgreedUnloadingDay, d.ArrivalUnloadingDay, d.DateTimeUnloading, d.PossitionAt8, d.PossitionAt15, d.NextLoading, d.PossitionNumber, d.ExportImport, d.LoadingCustoms, d.UnloadingCustoms, d.InvoiceNumber, d.StatusCource, d.StatusTruck, d.Notes, e.id, e.Names 
FROM dbo.ClientQueries d
FULL JOIN dbo.Employee e ON d.Driver1 = e.id )
        AS TEST 
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($tsql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

/* Determine which row numbers to display. */
if(isset($_GET['lowRowNum']) && isset($_GET['highRowNum']))
{
    $lowRowNum = $_GET['lowRowNum'];
    $highRowNum = $_GET['highRowNum'];
}
else
{
    $lowRowNum = 1;
    $highRowNum = $rowsPerPage;
}

/* Execute the query with parameter values. */
$sth->execute(array($lowRowNum, $highRowNum));

$numRows = $sth->rowCount(); 

if($numRows <= 0) 
{ 
    echo "No data returned.</br>"; 
} 
else 
{ 

 echo '<h3>Преглед записи </h3>';
    print("<table class='mytable'>
           <tr class='headertb'>

        <td class='bold'>SqlInsertDate</td>
           <td class='bold'>PACourceNumber</td>
           <td class='bold'>ClientQuerydate</td>
           <td class='bold'>ClientName</td>
           <td class='bold'>SpeditorName</td>
           <td class='bold'>CourseType</td>
           <td class='bold'>Driver</td>
           <td class='bold'>Driver2</td>
           <td class='bold'>TruckRegisteredNumber</td>
           <td class='bold'>TrailerRegisteredNumber</td>
           <td class='bold'>StartWorkingDay</td>
           <td class='bold'>LoadingAddress</td>
           <td class='bold'>UnloadingAddress</td>
           <td class='bold'>AgreedLoadingDay</td>
           <td class='bold'>DateTimeLoading</td>
           <td class='bold'>DateTimeUnloading</td>
           <td class='bold'>PossitionAt8</td>
           <td class='bold'>PossitionAt15</td>
           <td class='bold'>PossitionNumber</td>
           <td class='bold'>StatusCource</td>
           <td class='bold'>StatusTruck</td>
           <td class='bold'>Notes</td>             
            <td class='bold'>Редакция</td>
            </tr>");

    /*Display all but the last of the rows in the result set.*/ 
    for($i=0; $i<$numRows-1; $i++) 
    { 
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
        print("<tr>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td>
            <td>$row[3]</td>
            <td>$row[4]</td>
            <td>$row[5]</td>
            <td>$row[6]</td>
            <td>$row[7]</td>
            <td>$row[8]</td>
            <td>$row[9]</td>
            <td>$row[10]</td>
            <td>$row[11]</td>
            <td>$row[12]</td>
            <td>$row[13]</td>
            <td>$row[14]</td>
            <td>$row[15]</td>
            <td>$row[16]</td>
            <td>$row[17]</td>
            <td>$row[18]</td>
            <td>$row[19]</td>
            <td>$row[20]</td>
            <td>$row[21]</td>
            <td>$row[22]</td>
            <td>$row[23]</td>
            <td>$row[24]</td>
            <td>$row[25]</td>
            <td><a href=update.php?id=$row[1]>Редакция</a></td></tr>"); 
    } 
    /*Display the last row in the result set if 
      there isn't another page of results.*/ 
    if($numRows <=20) 
    { 
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
        print("<tr>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td>
            <td>$row[3]</td>
            <td>$row[4]</td>
            <td>$row[5]</td>
            <td>$row[6]</td>
            <td>$row[7]</td>
            <td>$row[8]</td>
            <td>$row[9]</td>
            <td>$row[10]</td>
            <td>$row[11]</td>
            <td>$row[12]</td>
            <td>$row[13]</td>
            <td>$row[14]</td>
            <td>$row[15]</td>
            <td>$row[16]</td>
            <td>$row[17]</td>
            <td>$row[18]</td>
            <td>$row[19]</td>
            <td>$row[20]</td>
            <td>$row[21]</td>
            <td>$row[22]</td>
            <td>$row[23]</td>
            <td>$row[24]</td>
            <td>$row[25]</td>
            <td><a href=update.php?id=$row[1]>Редакция</a></td>
            </tr>"); 
    } 

    print("</table></br></br>"); 
    /* If there are previous results, 
        display the Previous Page link. */ 
    if($lowRowNum > 1) 
    { 
        $prev_page_high = $lowRowNum - 1; 
        $prev_page_low = $prev_page_high - $rowsPerPage + 1; 
        $prevPage = "?lowRowNum=$prev_page_low&".
                     "highRowNum=$prev_page_high"; 
        print("<a href=$prevPage><< Предишна страница</a>".
               "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"); 
    } 
    /* If there are more results, display the Next Page link.   
       We know there are more results if the query returned 11 rows. */ 
    if($numRows >= 21) 
    {        
        $next_page_low = $highRowNum + 1; 
        $next_page_high = $next_page_low + $rowsPerPage - 1; 
        $nextPage = "?lowRowNum=$next_page_low&".
                     "highRowNum=$next_page_high"; 
        print("<a href=$nextPage>Следваща страница >></a>"); 
    } 
}
 }
catch(Exception $e)
 { 
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend give me the answer to me.
So the answer is in the JOIN clause, it should be `INNER JOIN` not `FULL JOIN`. And instead of this `$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` have to change to this `$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);` and have to use named parameters where i need.